# What symmetry present in a low energy theory is broken or not exact at high energies?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry, effective-field-theory

The opposite is quite common such as EWSB, SUSY or GUT. Is there any example where a certain symmetry emerges from a low energy effective theory but is not present in the high energy theory?

Comment: Plenty of examples in condensed matter and statistical mechanics. The Ising model has a critical point described by a CFT. Almost the whole conformal symmetry is emergent. There are also many examples of emergent internal symmetry.

Comment: One of the example is superconduction where at low temperatures the electrons behaves like super electrons which follow translational symmetry, zero resistance everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, if you have a model with the right degrees of freedom to be supersymmetric in the absence of interactions and is infrared free otherwise, the RG will drive you away from the low energy supersymmetric limit at high energies, as first demonstrated in [*Stability and supersymmetry: General formalism and explicit two-loop applications*,  Curtright & Ghandour,
*Ann Phys* **106** (1977) 209-278](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(77)90312-8).

So, supersymmetry is unstable to high energy evolution, cf. the upper portion of the two couplings in this scalar multiplet manqué,
[image]
For supersymmetry, the scalar self-coupling, *f*, must equal the square of the Yukawa coupling, *g*. A small departure from the supersymmetry line amplifies to a substantial one at high energies.

Answer (score 0):

Low energy effective theory does not in general extend to all energy scales. The reason is that the symmetries cannot be rotated in the Lagrangian. This then means that at intermediate energy intervals, for example the proton - electron mass difference, the intermediate particles/fields that enter the Lagrangian carry conserved global quantum numbers that cannot be rotated away or removed by scaling appropriately. If there is an exact symmetry that forbids such an intermediate particle, then there can be no symmetry at low energies.
In this way, discrete symmetries such as $Z_2$ and CP etc cannot be exact at all energies. In this analogy with the behaviour of a remnant discrete symmetry in QCD, we can imagine the analogue to the gauge fields having symmetry breaking order parameters, but that the same discrete symmetries are still perturbative at high energies, and of course computable, so that long as we do not consider strong correlations.